# How to retrieve committed information from svn using Api?

Tags: svn

How to retrieve information of people who committed code into SVN repository using API.

Comment: If you really ask about API, then the first step would be to read the documentation http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.developer.usingapi.html. Ask questions only if you have any questions, don't ask for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a svn server on the same maschine, than can you read the logfile from the svn-server.
Example for run the server for a own logfile location is:
svnserve -d -r /svn --log-file=/var/log/svnserve.log